# @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) doesn't work with org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor..HibernateJpaVendorAdapter?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have one-to-many bidirectional relationship between Employer and Employees.
In `Employee` entity I want to fetch eagerly `Employer` instance.

My `Employee` entity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE", schema = "hibernatesimpledb")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
................
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Employer employer;
.....................
}
```

My spring configuration for `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.livelessons.spring.springcore.entities" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The problem is that hibernate generates two select statements when selecting single `Employee` entity. One select is for `Employee` and another is for `Employer`.

Why `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` doesn't work with `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`?

Comment: Remove `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`.

Comment: Fetch types does not work on JPA.

Comment: Is there a way to select owner and associations in one query with JPA?

Comment: I am really confused but it began to work. JPA uses INNER JOIN to fetch associated employer.

Comment: `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` is not needed!